# I tried to use vue-resource and I got "Uncaught TypeError: window.Vue.use is not a function"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-resource

I am new to Vue.js and recently, I tried to use vue-resource but I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.Vue.use is not a function
   at vue-resource.js:1469
   at vue-resource.js:10
   at vue-resource.js:11
```

**I am using Vue 3.0.7 and vue-resource 1.5.2**

I tried to look for the error in the vue-resource source code in `node_modules/vue-resource/dist/vue-resource.js` and there was this block of code at line 1469:

```
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.Vue && !window.Vue.resource) {
      window.Vue.use(plugin);
    }
```

I tried writing `window.Vue` in the browser console of `localhost:3000` and it was defined but `window.Vue.use` wasn't.

this is the end of the body tag of my `index.html` file:

```
<!--some code -->
  <!-- Scripts -->
  <!-- adding hot reload -->
  <script src="/reload/reload.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/vue/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/vue-resource/dist/vue-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="public/script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

This is the method I have defined in the `methods` property to use vue-resource :

```
            onSubmit() {
                console.log("Search");
                let path = "/search?q=".concat(this.search);
                this.$http.get(path)
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found out that vue-resource doesn't support vue3. It is written in npmjs.com that:
*Supports Vue 1.0 & Vue 2.0*. And vue3 isn't mentioned.